# Autoscroll with setInterval/clearInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, autoscroll, clearinterval

Im relatively new to JS coding, and can't get this little number to work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My JavaScript is:

```
    incrementScroll = function() {
        window.scrollBy(0, 3) ;
    }

    startScrollLoop = function() {
        scrollLoopId = setInterval( "incrementScroll", 5) ; 
    }

    stopScrollLoop = function() {
        clearInterval( scrollLoopId ) ;
    }
```

And my HTML is:

```
<button onclick="startScrollLoop()">AUTO SCROLL</button>
<button onclick="stopScrollLoop ()">STOP SCROLL</button>
```

Again, many thanks for help. New to all of this and need to make a project work by morning.
Cheers.

Comment: This might not solve your problem but you should not set an interval that uses a smaller interval time than the period of one frame (browser fps) which is about 16 milliseconds (if it runs at normal speed): `setInterval( incrementScroll, 20 );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `setInterval()` should be a function reference, or non-ideally, a string to be eval()'d, which would be a complete function call with `()`.  So remove the quotes:

```
// Pass the reference to incrementScroll, 
// not a quoted string containing its name.
scrollLoopId = setInterval(incrementScroll, 5);
```

And to clear the scroll, you will need to define `scrollLoopId` at a higher scope with `var`.

```
// Define outside the function so it is available
// in scope of the stopScrollLoop() function when needed...
var scrollLoopId;
var startScrollLoop = function() {
    scrollLoopId = setInterval( incrementScroll, 5) ; 
}
```

#### [Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Uf3Nb/1/)

(uses a slower scroll speed to give you a chance to click the stop button in the middle of the text)

Note that it is good practice to use the `var` keyword with each of these. even though they would end up at `window` scope anyway (assuming they're not being defined inside another function).

```
// Define with var
var incrementScroll = function() {
  window.scrollBy(0, 3);
}
```

Comment: Eureka! Works great. Thanks so much. The internet really can do your homework for you! The site (still very much in development) is here: johnnyvenom.org.